# Unity 2D Simple directional blend: one direction ignored

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in Unity that involves a Paper Mario-esque movement system, which entails four positions: facing right from the side, facing right from the back, and facing left for both. This means there is no specific animation for down.

What I've done is created a Blend Tree with a 2D Simple Directional type, transitioned to from an "Idle" default state. However, although I've set things up fairly simply (1,0; 1,1; -1,0; -1,1) and one of my directions (specifically, (1, 0)) doesn't work. After some experimentation I've discovered it's "clipping" the 1,0 off just above y=0. So (-1, 0) works as it should and (1, 0.1) works but (1, 0) does not.

[image: Here's] This is a screenshot of the issue. What exactly is going wrong?

Is this related to what I assume is an error about the 180 degree separation?

Comment: My guess is that the "less than 180 degrees" part means *strictly* less than 180 degrees, not "less than or equal to."

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: Setting the Y value to `0.001`

Comment: If I do that, the cut-off point now becomes everything south of y=.001, and xInput of anything from -1 to 1 when y=0 isn't tracked.

Comment: Well, yeah. Because you have to stay within the valid range. When X > 0, then Y > 0

Comment: How about situations where I want Y = 0? Say "xInput" is taken from pressing left and right on my keyboard and "yInput" from up and down. Let's say I only press the right key, and that gives me (after a moment) X = 1 and Y = 0. How does your suggestion account for that use case?

Comment: I don't know, I've never messed with it. I can only take a stab at why it does what it does.